# Assign and use javascript object property via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, javascript-objects

So I have this Javascript object :

```
var obj = { 
    conn : null,
    first : function(thisIdentity) {
        "use strict";
        $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax ({ 
            url : some value,
            // other parameters
            success : function() {
                this.conn = new Connection(data.user_id, "127.0.0.1:80");
            }
        });
   },
    second : function(thisIdentity) {
        "use strict";
        $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax ({ 
                url : some value,
                // other parameters
                success : function() { 
                    // using this.conn now results in UNDEFINED
                }
            });
    }
};
```

Now basically value is assigned to conn variable in AJAX call of first function but when I try to use the same value in second function then it states **this.conn is undefined**. I just want to know how to assign value to the object's property and keep it preserved for future use? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the ajax success callback the **`this`** refers to a different scope than the original object.

Change you code to this:

```
var obj = { 
conn : null,
first : function(thisIdentity) {
    "use strict";
    var mySelf = this;
    $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax ({ 
        url : some value,
        // other parameters
        success : function() {
            mySelf.conn = new Connection(data.user_id, "127.0.0.1:80");
        }
    });
},
second : function(thisIdentity) {
    "use strict";
    var mySelf = this;
    $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax ({ 
            url : some value,
            // other parameters
            success : function() { 
                // now you can access the connection with mySelf.conn
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this but still it is saying `self.conn` is null. Value is being assigned in the first function but when I use it in next then it says it is null.

Comment: `self` is a keyword, which is similar to `this`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar no it isn't

Comment: @Musa Can you kindly explain the difference, thanks. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar `self` is not a keyword, `this` is

Comment: @Musa [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) **is** a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax itself is wrong. You are creating a variable or giving an expression inside an object literal. Remember this is not a function, but instead, it should be:

```
$.ajax ({ 
    // computation and in success function 
    conn: new Connection(data.user_id, "127.0.0.1:80")
});
```

**Updated**

When you are giving such a way of definition:

```
success : function() {
    this.conn = new Connection(data.user_id, "127.0.0.1:80");
}
```

Here, the `this` object refers to the `success` function and not your `object`. Read [Understanding Scope and Context in JavaScript](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/). Now you need to create a proxy variable for `this` and use it:

```
first : function(thisIdentity) {
    "use strict";
    var myObj = this;
    $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax ({ 
        url : some value,
        // other parameters
        success : function() {
            myObj.conn = new Connection(data.user_id, "127.0.0.1:80");
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: I think OP did a terrible job of posting the code, that line is actually in the success callback. Also there is no `conn` parameter in jQuery.ajax.

Comment: The `conn` is OP's defined variable I guess. It is there in the top.

Comment: @PraveenKumar @Musa `conn` is pre-defined as Object's property and it is being assigned in the callback function/success function.
`success : function() {
      this.conn =new Connection(data.user_id, "127.0.0.1:80");
}`

Comment: @Yomesh Yeah, but that's not a function buddy, your syntax is wrong. So make it as `success: function () {}` and add your contents there.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Check my comment and edited post again please. I have added my content in `success : function() {}` only.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I tried this but still it is saying `myObj.conn` is null. Value is being assigned in the first function but when I use it in next then it says it is null.

Comment: @Yomesh Just remove `myObj` and please use just `conn =`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable conn
This is the error now.

Comment: @Yomesh Do you really require `"use strict";`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not really but removing it also doesn't solve the purpose. Using just `conn =` assigns the variable locally and does not update the object's property so in second function it is still null.

Comment: @Yomesh I guess you are fundamentally doing a mistake. Not sure where. `:(`

Comment: Basic context is : 
When a user logs in then a connection is made and his/her user_id is stored with the server. 
`myObj.conn = new Connection(data.user_id, url)` 
basically provides a connection and in second function when user lets say likes someone's post then 
`myObj.conn.sendMsg(parameters)` is used to send a notification to that user but it is saying `myObj.conn` is null! I don't understand where "fundamentally" I am wrong! :(